# Parsing bit based messages in C++

Tags: python, c++

is there some C++ alternative to construct from python? I'm getting bit based packets like this one (the numbers are bits):

```
Packet_Icon:{
   packet_id:8,
   packet_lenght:13,
   n_fields:5,
   fields:{
       indicator_id:8,
       position_id:5,
       text_lenght:5,
       text:{
           bytes:8
       }
   }
}
```

Which I would like to deserialize to some easy to use class. I know protocol buffers, but I've concluded it's impossible to define such a packet with them. Am I right?

This question is similar to:
[C++ equivalent of Python's “construct” library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108425/c-equivalent-of-pythons-construct-library)

Note that the packet size (stored in 13 bits variable packet_lenght) can be anything between 26 and 8192 bits (2^13).

Comment: I can't tell what your input is, and what your output should be. Do you have this type and want to expose it to Python? Do you have something else you want to populate this type from?

Comment: I have that packet and I would like to parse it in c++ app. For testing I have it already in Python using construct where this task is really a piece of cake. But is there something for C++?

Comment: I misread your question and thought you were looking for a Python library.  These python libraries emulate a standard C approach to implementing [bitfields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).  So you're in luck.

Comment: @jedwards unfortunately c++ bitfields are static, what I need is constructs ability to decode packets with dynamic content.

Comment: @jedwards: not exactly. Python one is only **one** of the possible implementation of C bitfields. And I have no trust in all C or C++ implementation to be compatible...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "bitfields" in C++ (or C):

```
struct Packet_Icon {
   unsigned packet_id:8;
   unsigned packet_length:13;
   unsigned n_fields:5;
   unsigned indicator_id:8;
   unsigned position_id:5;
   unsigned text_lenght:5;
   unsigned text:8;
   unsigned pad:4;
};
static_assert(sizeof(Packet_Icon) == 7, "wrong size");
```

Your original was 52 bits total, so you'll need to figure out how to deal with the fact that any device you read from is likely to give you whole bytes (not 6.5 bytes).  I added an explicit 4 bit pad to make it clearer what's happening (and to make those bits accessible to the program).

Comment: Are you sure that the standard is explicit on the actual endianness of a bit field?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: No.  Caveat experior.

Comment: I suspect n_fields is a count of fields, which wouldn't work here.

Comment: @JohnZwinck the n_count is count of following fields as text_lenght is length of the text (max 32 bytes). Those "bitfields" are unfortunately too static.

Comment: @LiborTomsik: Well then use bitfields for the static header portion and the individual fields, and write logic for the rest.  Or do it all with bit manipulation operators.

Comment: @JohnZwinck that's what I was trying to avoid with some high level description like python construct or protocol buffers does. My packets could change at customers whim, so in sake of maintainability I'd like having it separate from code and as configurable as possible.

Comment: shouldn't a `uint8_t` be used?

Comment: @J.Doe: Irrelevant.  It only has to be large enough (e.g. you can't use `uint8_t packet_length`).

Comment: @LiborTomsik: Then you should probably write a library to do this.  Perhaps using code generation if performance is very important.  Or, find a library (but note we won't recommend libraries on this site).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I was hoping there is something ready, like in boost, what I'm unable to google